# Slick generates nested SQL

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to make virtual table and join it to real table when needed.
I'm using slick 3.0 for compatibility reasons. 
Database is MySql.

Code looks like this:

```
def linkTable(data: Seq[(Int, Int)]): Query[(Rep[Int], Rep[Int]), (Int, Int), Seq] = {

      val tableRows: Seq[Query[(ConstColumn[Int], ConstColumn[Int]), (Int, Int), Seq]] = {
        data.map { case (groupId, merchantId) =>
          Query(groupId, merchantId)
        }
      }

      if (tableRows.isEmpty) {
        Query(-1, -1)
      } else {
        tableRows.reduceLeft(_ union _)
      }
    }
```

The result type:

```
Query[(Rep[Int], Rep[Int]), (Int, Int), Seq]
```

is exactly what I need for being able to integrate virtual table into codebase.

Function *linkTable* works just fine except for the fact that it generated nested sql:

```
    (SELECT x7.x8  AS x9,
            x7.x10 AS x11
    FROM   (
             SELECT x12.x13 AS x8,
                    x12.x14 AS x10
             FROM   (
                      SELECT x15.x16 AS x13,
                             x15.x17 AS x14
                      FROM   (
                               SELECT 1 AS x16,
                                      3 AS x17
                               FROM   DUAL
                               UNION
                               SELECT 2 AS x16,
                                      3 AS x17
                               FROM   DUAL) x15
                      UNION
                      SELECT 3 AS x13,
                             3 AS x14
                      FROM   DUAL) x12
             UNION
             SELECT 4 AS x8,
                    3 AS x10
             FROM   DUAL) x7
             UNION
             SELECT 5 AS x9,
                    3 AS x11
             FROM   DUAL) x18
```

Which leads to following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Too high level of nesting for select
```

What I need is to make those unions flat:

```
    (SELECT 1 AS x7,
           3 AS x8
    FROM   DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS x7,
           3 AS x8
    FROM   DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS x7,
           3 AS x8
    FROM   DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS x7,
           3 AS x8
    FROM   DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT 5 AS x7,
           3 AS x8
    FROM   DUAL
    ) x9
```

Someone knows how to make it happen with slick 3.0 ?
Making query from string is valid option but result type should be correct.

Comment: How about raw SQL in slick ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, as I said it's a good option. But I don't understand how to do it and get correct result type. Can you show some kind of example ?.